# Unable to use conda in JupyterHub

Tags: installation, conda, jupyterhub

I am currently using "the littlest JupyterHub."
When I following the guide and try to use conda to install some package, it comes up with this message and seems like noting have been done.

```
$ sudo -E conda install -c conda-forge gdal
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): | Killed
```

What should I do to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: FYI: Use of `sudo` is typically a sign of misconfigured Conda. Only sys admins managing multi-user installs should be using it.